# Calculating the volume of a rasterpixel in R

Tags: r, raster, volume

I am performing a time series analysis on raster data (DEMs) from coastal regions. I want to measure the difference in volume (sand) between 2 different time stamps. I have already calculated the difference in height trough DEM differencing, but I do not know how to calculate the volume from that.

I have resampled the two rasters, so they now have the same resolution.

```
dem1 = resample(dem1, dem18)
```

DEM1

```
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 5076, 6722, 34120872  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.0464469, 0.0464469  (x, y)
extent     : 49584.86, 49897.07, 215276.8, 215512.6  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=lcc +lat_0=90 +lon_0=4.36748666666667 +lat_1=51.1666672333333 +lat_2=49.8333339 +x_0=150000.013 +y_0=5400088.438 +ellps=intl +units=m +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : X20210223_DUDE_Oostende_T1_DEM 
values     : 3.852022, 19.46622  (min, max)
```

DEM18

```
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 5076, 6722, 34120872  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.0464469, 0.0464469  (x, y)
extent     : 49584.86, 49897.07, 215276.8, 215512.6  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=lcc +lat_0=90 +lon_0=4.36748666666667 +lat_1=51.1666672333333 +lat_2=49.8333339 +x_0=150000.013 +y_0=5400088.438 +ellps=intl +units=m +no_defs 
source     : 20220912_0216419_DUDE Oostende_T18_DEM.tif 
names      : X20220912_0216419_DUDE_Oostende_T18_DEM
```

I have subtracted both to measure the elevation difference.

```
elevation_difference = dem18 - dem1
```

I receive the plot below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qfx7v.png)

I now want to calculate the changes in volume of sand. Is is just elevation_difference * the size of the pixel?

Comment: What's your dem resolution, assuming `terra::res(dem18_2[1]` == `sqrt(2,5)`?

Comment: The DEM resolution is 4.64 cm, after the resampling (turns out dem1 has a resolution of 2.5 cm and dem18 of 46.4 cm)

Comment: It would likely help if you put summary of `dem1`, `dem18`, and `dem18_2` above, and usually links to data are helpful so we are looking at your problem as you are. `resample` 'should' apportion the values in dem18, across the geometry of dem1, i.e. dem18_2 should have the same resolution as dem1...then subtraction to derive net volume makes sense (at least to me). And what steps (in code) led to dem1 and dem18?

Comment: So, we look at `windy_beach_area <- terra::area`, `?terra:area`and scratch our heads a little, if by-cell volume wanted , sum = FALSE, lambert isn't equal area, so correct = TRUE, for either dem1 or dem18, then  wba_1 <- windy_beach_area * dem1, wba_18 <- windy_beach_area * dem18, net_vol_by_cell <- wba18 - wba1. I think.

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work, I also do not fully understand where to use the correction for Lambert projection, sorry.

Comment: Sorry, `cellSize` for head scratching...looks like defaults will do it. , returns a numeric, i.e. area of cell, in 'm', then that times dem1, dem18...volume by cell, then subtract to net.

Comment: How's it going?

Comment: Great. Now, close the virtuous loop by writing up your working code as an answer, come back and accept it, as answered questions help most for future searchers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dem1  = raster("20210223_DUDE_Oostende_T1_DEM.tif")
dem18 = raster("20220912_0216419_DUDE Oostende_T18_DEM.tif")

dem1 = resample(dem1, dem18)

stacked = stack(dem1, dem18)
plot(stacked, xlim = x_lim, ylim = y_lim, col = terrain.colors(100))
```

[image]

```
# elevation difference

elevation_difference = dem18 - dem1
plot(elevation_difference, main = "Changes in height in m", col=terrain.colors(100), xlim = x_lim, ylim = y_lim)

# volume difference: height is in meter, pixels are in cm

area_pixel = prod(res(dem_stacked)) # the area of a cell is the product of the resolution in x and y
area_pixel # in cm²!
volume_difference = (elevation_difference$layer*100) * area_pixel
plot(volume_difference, main = "Changes in volume sand", col=terrain.colors(100), xlim = x_lim, ylim = y_lim)
```

[image]
[image]

Normally the units should be correct, but better check it out :)